# How does jenkins declarative pipeline define arrays

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

[docs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin)

I want to define volumes and envVars, but I get an error

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        kubernetes {
            idleMinutes 5
            workspaceVolume nfsWorkspaceVolume(readOnly: false, serverAddress: '127.0.0.1', serverPath: '/data/nfs-data/kubernetes/jenkins/agent')
            containerTemplate {
                name 'maven'
                image 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine'
                ttyEnabled true
                command 'cat'
                envVars envVar( key: 'ENV', value: 'test')
          }
            }
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clone') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'pwd'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running a pipeline script gives following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface java.util.List is using symbol ‘envVar’
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:570)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.UninstantiatedDescribable.instantiate(UninstantiatedDescribable.java:207)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:466)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:429)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:331)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {image=maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine, ttyEnabled=true, name=maven, envVars=@envVar(key=127.0.0.1,value=/data/nfs-data/kubernetes/jenkins/agent), command=cat} for org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.ContainerTemplate
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:474)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:429)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:331)
```

What should I do??

Comment: It is in the documentation you linked against here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#container-configuration